# PHP Find words into string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have the following keywords. I want that the final answer (could be answer_1, answer_2, answer_3) to be the one that contains the keywords in "question".

```
$question = 'how old are you'

$key_word_1 = array('old', 'are');
$answer_1 = 'this is my age';

$key_word_2 = array('yes', 'no');
$answer_2 = 'this is a question';

$key_word_3 = array('tall', 'short');
$answer_3 = 'this are my measures';

$key_word_4 = array('back', 'blue');
$answer_4 = 'My colorus';

echo $final_answer;
'this is my age' . #----> because 'old' and 'are' are contained in $question
```

Comment: You would need to split the string and then loop over each index and check it against each question, adding one to the count. However, what if you end up with an even split (one word in two different questions, with two words total)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way (using `array_intersect`):

```
$question = 'how old are you';

$question_array = explode(' ',$question);

$answers_array[0]['keywords'] = array('old', 'are');
$answers_array[0]['answer'] = 'this is my age';

$answers_array[1]['keywords'] = array('yes', 'no');
$answers_array[1]['answer'] = 'this is a question';

$answers_array[2]['keywords'] = array('tall', 'short');
$answers_array[2]['answer'] = 'this are my measures';

$answers_array[3]['keywords'] = array('back', 'blue');
$answers_array[3]['answer'] = 'My colorus';

foreach($answers_array as $key=> $answer)
{
    if(sizeof(array_intersect($answers_array[$key]['keywords'], $question_array)) == sizeof($answers_array[$key]['keywords']))
    {
        $final_answer = $answers_array[$key]['answer'];
    }
}

echo $final_answer;
```

Comment: Excellent, I think I failed to clarify that at least 1 condition must be met. You don't have to meet both. Therefore, with "how are you", I should also return "this is my age".